# webform in magento not working

Tags: magento

I installed webform in my magento and then tried to remove 'Powered by Magento'.
I tried to change `app/code/community/VladimirPopov/WebForms/Block/webforms.php`.

In Webform.php file, code is fully encoded.By searching it From Google, I got alternative webform.php.So that, it 'Powered by Magento' is removed.But after that, webform is not working or form with Ajax submission is not working.I am New in magento.

Is 'webform not working' it related with 'Powered by Magento'. If there is another issue, please, help me.In Error console, it shows `'webform_myid_submit is not a function'`.If any one knows about it, please reply.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check if you import jQuery or prototype.js lib twice.

I have the similar problem and has been fixed by this way.